# DotNetOpenAuth - IsReturnUrlDiscoverable never true in OpenIdProviderMvc

Tags: openid, dotnetopenauth, provider

I'm trying to implement an OpenId Provider. I'm using the OpenIdProviderMvc and OpenIdRelyingPartyMvc projects.
The OpenIdController::AutoRespondIfPossible() method never returns true. On investigation, I found out that HostProcessRequest.cs::IsReturnUrlDiscoverableCore never returns success. Specifically, this lines seem to be the problem:

```
if (discoveredReturnToUrl.Contains(this.RequestMessage.ReturnTo)) {
// no need to keep looking after we find a match
    return RelyingPartyDiscoveryResult.Success;
}
```

Because the discoveredReturnToUrl is https:///OpenIdRelyingPartyMvc/user/authenticate

while the return To url is https:///OpenIdRelyingPartyMvc/User/Authenticate?ReturnUrl=Index&dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier=https%3A%2F%2F%2FOpenIdProviderMvc%2Fuser%2Fbob

This doesn't seem right. Can you confirm this is the right behavior or if this is a bug?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds likely to be the capitalization difference between the two URLs.

And if that seems silly to you, take a look at [The case for case sensitive OpenID URL checking](http://blog.nerdbank.net/2008/07/case-for-case-sensitive-openid-url.html).

Comment: Hmmm... that could be one reason. But look at the code again, shouldn't it be this.RequestMessage.ReturnTo.Contains(discoveredReturnToUrl) ?

Comment: No.  This Contains method is perhaps poorly named.  It's not a substring or collection search.  It's a "does this URL match, or fall within, this Realm?"  The discoveredReturnToUrl is a `Realm` instance, so we're asking if the return_to in the request message is allowed under this realm.  The code is correct.  And the case sensitivity will definitely cause Realm.Contains to return false in your case.